# How to select an iframe and pass its src to a function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

I have a javascript file that displays a variable number of videos embedded from youtube and displayed in a grid.
I need the users to be able to select one video and click submit where I will will store the src link of that video in a variable.

Below is the related javascript portion:

```
 playListItems.forEach(item => {
      const videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
      output += `
        <div class="col s3">
        <iframe width="100%" id="videoFrame" height="auto" 
         src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?rel=0" frameborder="0" encrypted-media" > 
         </iframe></div>
      `;
  }
```

HTML:

```
   <form id="form1">
       <div class="input-field">
          <input type="submit" id="but1" value="Save Selection">
       </div>
   </form>
```

How do I do that using an event handler or any other possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use `const videoId` as the `id` of each iframe? Because you can't use an id more then once. Then in an `onclick` handler of each iframe element you can fire a function that sets the value of `<input type="submit" id="but1" value="Save Selection">` to `this.id`. 
Like so:

```js
 playListItems.forEach(item => {
      const videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
      output += '<div class="col s3">
        <iframe width="100%" id="${videoId}" height="auto" 
         src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?rel=0" frameborder="0" encrypted-media" onclick='submitVid(this.id);'> 
         </iframe></div>';
  }
```

Then the `submitVid(video)` function will look something like this:

```js
function submitVid(video) {
   //the video variable will hold this.id or the videoId
   //Here you can do whatever you want with video.
   //Full video id:
   var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video + "?rel=0";
   //pass value to a textfield to submit
   document.getElementById("textfield").value = video;
}
```

A better is to just store the `videoId` and not the full url. It saves space and it is faster.

Hope this helps! If not, please comment

Comment: Thank you Chiel. The issue I face now is that the iframe is not clickable. When I added your code to a div before or after the iframe and triggered the onclick function from that div it works fine. But adding the onclick to the iframe tag does not seem to work.

Comment: I also tried adding an invisible container on top of the video and added the onclick to it, but I get the same result. 
    .invisible{position:relative;float:left;}
    .overlay{top:0;left:0;position:absolute;}

Comment: @YoussefHassoun do you want the video to be playable and selectable? And was the video playable when the onclick function was on the div?

Comment: The video was playable when the onclick function was on div. Your first question made me re-think of how this could make more sense. I think it is better to add a small button below the iframe to select the video, I just initially didnt want too many buttons for styling purposes. Nevertheless, I am interested to know how I can override the play onclick and activate the select onclick.

Comment: @YoussefHassoun Take note that the padding, margin and or border of the iframe are clickable. You could for example tell users to click on the top border of a video to select it. Then you could change the color of the top border from red to green. Hope this gives some valuable insights!

Answer (score 0):

try *some_var = document.getElementById("videoFrame").src*

Comment: Because it is in a loop, wont the src always have the last video src? how will it know which one is selected?

Comment: the variable will the src of the video user last clicked which is what you want right?

Comment: Yes exactly only the last choice.